# Llenar dataframe en R en funcion de valores de la columna principal y de la fila principal

Tags: r

perdón por el título pero es dificil de explicar, creo que con un ejemplo es mejor.

Supongamos que tengo un dataframe u otro que me muestra la información de cantidad de dinero en distintas monedas para cada persona, una tabla como la que muestro a continuación:

[image: original]

Ejemplo:

```
 df <- data.frame(NOMBRE=c('JUAN','JUAN', 'PEDRO', 'PEDRO', 'PEDRO', 'LUIS', 'LUIS'),
                  MONEDA=c('EUR', 'USD', 'EUR', 'CLP', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR'),
                  MONTO=c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10))
```

El problema es que necesito hacer una matriz consolidada con las monedas como columna y donde me busque la información para cada persona distinta en función del primer dataframe. El aspecto de este dataframe sería el siguiente:

[image: DAtaframe]

Lo que necesito es una funcion o algo en R que me permita llenar la información de lo que se muestra en amarillo

Soy un poco novato en R y no he encontrado una preguntar similar.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no tienes problemas en incorporar funcionalidad extra, te recomiendo que uses los paquetes `dplyr` y `tdyr`, a menos que busques dominar la funcionalidad base de R, estos paquetes son muy útiles para el que está comenzando por que ofrecen una semántica más sencilla y clara para resolver muchos requerimientos en cuanto a manipulación de datos:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(NOMBRE) %>% 
  spread(MONEDA, MONTO)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   NOMBRE [3]
  NOMBRE   CLP   EUR   GBP   USD
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 JUAN      NA    10    NA    20
2 LUIS      NA    10    30    NA
3 PEDRO     10    30    NA    20
```

Detalle:

- Por empezar usamos el operador "infix" `%>%` o pipe/pipa, el cual permite "concatenar" la salida de una función con la entrada de la otra, lo cual hace más legible el código.
- Con `group_by` agrupamos los datos por `NOMBRE`
- Con `spread` "desplegamos" `MONEDA` y sus respectivos `MONTO` a lo ancho
- La salida es un objeto `tibble` que para el caso no mucho más distinto que un `data.frame` básico de **R**

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una forma simple es usando la funcionalidad "base" de **R** mediante [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html):

```
df <- data.frame(NOMBRE=c('JUAN','JUAN', 'PEDRO', 'PEDRO', 'PEDRO', 'LUIS', 'LUIS'),
                  MONEDA=c('EUR', 'USD', 'EUR', 'CLP', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR'),
                  MONTO=c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10))

 reshape(data=df, 
         direction="wide", 
         idvar = "NOMBRE",
         timevar="MONEDA"
 ) 

  NOMBRE MONTO.EUR MONTO.USD MONTO.CLP MONTO.GBP
1   JUAN        10        20        NA        NA
3  PEDRO        30        20        10        NA
6   LUIS        10        NA        NA        30
```

No demasiado distinto a lo que buscas, para hacerlo exacto, faltaría reordenar las columnas y renombrarlas:

```
new <- new[, c(1, order(colnames(new[,-1])) + 1)]
colnames(new)[-1] <- as.character(unique(df$MONEDA))

  NOMBRE EUR USD CLP GBP
1   JUAN  NA  10  NA  20
3  PEDRO  10  30  NA  20
6   LUIS  NA  10  30  NA
```

[`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html) es una función para "reformatear" un determinado objeto (`data=df`). En este caso hacia un formato "ancho" (`direction="wide"`), la columna que se agrupa es la de `NOMBRE` (`idvar = "NOMBRE"`) y la variable que expandiremos será `timevar="MONEDA"`.